# Ubuntu 20.04 add static route

Tags: networking, server, netplan

I have two virtual Servers with ubuntu 20.04, both are working so far. But my problem is, that Server1 can not ping Server2 and vice versa. I get the error 'Destination Host Unreachable'. This is with the domainname and also with the ip.
AFAIS this a wrong or missing route between this servers
I have found this tutorial https://contabo.com/blog/creating-static-routes/

But it don't work for me, and my config seams to be different.

My /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml looks like this:

```
  network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens18:
      match:
        macaddress: 00:50:56:46:a3:de
      addresses:
        - 38.242.229.xx/19
        #- 2a02:c206:3009:2902:0000:0000:0000:0001/64
      #gateway6: fe80::1
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 38.242.224.1
          on-link: true
      nameservers:
        search: [ invalid ]
        addresses:
          - 161.97.189.52
          - 161.97.189.51
          #- 2a02:c206:5028::2:53
          #- 2a02:c206:5028::1:53
```

Maybe someone can help that I can reach the other (second) server from this instance.
My knowledge about networking with Linux is not so good that I can change the tutorial to my needs.
Thank you.

ip addr:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:46:a3:de brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 38.242.229.72/19 brd 38.242.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe46:a3de/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:e1:f9:bb:15 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip route:

```
default via 38.242.224.1 dev eth0 proto static onlink
38.242.224.0/19 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 38.242.229.72
```

ip addr of second server:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:46:a3:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 38.242.229.63/19 brd 38.242.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:5f:77:59:e9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
55: br-195a84347f94: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:a6:46:7a:27 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.25.0.1/16 brd 172.25.255.255 scope global br-195a84347f94
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
57: vethb13ec38@if56: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-195a84347f94 state UP group default
    link/ether 92:e8:8a:e0:f1:7c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
59: veth21971c4@if58: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-195a84347f94 state UP group default
    link/ether 4e:95:40:7d:78:93 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 2
68: br-d0ad0289f7c7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:ef:83:ac:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.28.0.1/16 brd 172.28.255.255 scope global br-d0ad0289f7c7
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
70: veth07b736d@if69: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-d0ad0289f7c7 state UP group default
    link/ether f6:85:f1:48:45:8e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 3
74: br-c2c3481624b2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:e8:3c:59:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.30.0.1/16 brd 172.30.255.255 scope global br-c2c3481624b2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
76: veth98745d8@if75: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-c2c3481624b2 state UP group default
    link/ether 2a:70:8d:58:de:e8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    enter code here
```

ip route of second server:

```
default via 38.242.224.1 dev eth0 proto static onlink
38.242.224.0/19 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 38.242.229.63
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.25.0.0/16 dev br-195a84347f94 proto kernel scope link src 172.25.0.1
172.28.0.0/16 dev br-d0ad0289f7c7 proto kernel scope link src 172.28.0.1
172.30.0.0/16 dev br-c2c3481624b2 proto kernel scope link src 172.30.0.1
```

ping to gateway is working, also a ping to yahoo.com is working.

May goal is that the first server is able to clone/pull a git repository from gitlab which is running on the second server.

Every server can ping everything but not the other one. The hoster tells me that this is because both ip-addresses are in the same subnet and so I have to make a static root to solve this. But I am not able to follow the instructions in the link above for ubunto 20.04 with success.

Comment: Can you please run `ip addr` and `ip route` on both servers and add the output to your question?

Comment: added both infos

Comment: Thanks - You added the output for one of the servers, could you please add the same output for the other? That way we can check whether the routes make sense for reachability from one of them to the other. Also, can you ping the default gateway? (38.242.224.1 per what I can see). Can the servers reach other systems on the internet? (try `ping yahoo.com`)

Comment: edited the question with infos you need. 
In Short:
both server can ping the default gateway and both server can ping other systems on the internet

Comment: The network configuration you've posted shows that both are on the same logical network which means they should be able to talk to each other without going through any gateways.  However, it is unusual to have a netmask of /19, which would mean 8192 machines all in the same broadcast domain and able to talk directly to each other with no router in between.  If the provider said you should have a static route, what did they say that static route should *be*?

Comment: @slangasek That's my problem. They just say I have to make a static route described in https://contabo.com/blog/creating-static-routes/
But I don't really unterstand how to do this the right way, I tried nearly everything and had to reinstall the server several times.

Comment: Thanks, that gives the necessary information about the provider's network topology to give the correct configuration.  Answer forthcoming.

Comment: Could you please **answer your own question** and write down exactly what you did and share your fully working 01-netcfg.yaml?

Answer (score 0):

Per https://contabo.com/blog/creating-static-routes/, despite advertising that other servers are on the same subnet, you cannot reach them without going through the router.  Therefore the correct configuration should look like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens18:
      match:
        macaddress: 00:50:56:46:a3:de
      addresses:
        - 38.242.229.xx/32
        #- 2a02:c206:3009:2902:0000:0000:0000:0001/64
      #gateway6: fe80::1
      routes:
        - to: 38.242.224.1/32
          on-link: true
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 38.242.224.1
      nameservers:
        search: [ invalid ]
        addresses:
          - 161.97.189.52
          - 161.97.189.51
          #- 2a02:c206:5028::2:53
          #- 2a02:c206:5028::1:53
```

Note the use of host netmasks (/32) which represents your true network topology.

Comment: Hello!
Thank you for you help. But it was not correct for my case.
Support has told me after a few days:

address must be with /19
and as route must be added

- to: <ip server 2>/32
  via: 38.242.224.1

so now it is working. Thank you again for your help

Comment: Did you test the configuration I proposed above and find it lacking?  It should be equivalent to what you've been told by support, except that it should work correctly for ALL IPs in the netblock without the need to declare per-IP routes.

Comment: Yes, I tested it, but without luck. Maybe I did something wrong.